# count_chars_and_words from user in id return in span javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a Javascript newbie and I've been searching for the proper way to do this, but I just can't seem to get it right. I want to live count the characters and words in a user textarea (id) and display the answer on key up in two different spans.

I think the html is correct, it's just my javascript skill that is clearly lacking.

```js
function count_chars_and_words() {
  const textarea = document.getElementById("text_count").innerHTML.value;
  result = wc
  result = cc

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == ' ' && (text[i - 1] !== ' ' && text[i - 1] !== '\n')) {
      wc++;

    } else if (text[i] == '\n' && text[i - 1] !== ' ') {
      wc++;

      document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = wc;
      document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = cc;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words()"></textarea>
<p>Characters: <span id="char_count"></span><br/> Words: <span id="word_count"></span></p>
```

Comment: Can you use also jQuery or you need the answer just with js?

Comment: I need the answer with js. :(

Answer (score 1):

You're close, Your logic is fine. But you don't have any character counter increment. You are also not declaring in cc or wc. I modified your code but just a bit. I also added a replace function for multispaces. You can remove it if you want.

Here:

```js
function count_chars_and_words() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("text_count").value;
        var wc = 0;
        var cc = 0;
        //replace all multiple spaces with single space
        textarea = textarea.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
        
        for (let i = 0; i <textarea.length; i++) {
            cc++;
            if (textarea[i]==' ' && (textarea[i-1]!==' ' && textarea[i-1]!=='\n')) { 
                wc++;
            }
            else if(textarea[i]=='\n' && textarea[i-1]!==' '){
                wc++;
            }
            document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = wc;
            document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = cc; 
        } 
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words()"></textarea> 
<p>
    Characters: <span id="char_count"></span><br/>
    Words: <span id="word_count"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Ah. When I added the edit for the regex, I didn't change `const textarea` to `var textarea`. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop

You can only count the number of spaces and count them as one word

I suggest you read more about JavaScript

```js
function count_chars_and_words() {
  const textarea = document.getElementById("text_count").value;

  let word_count = textarea.split(' ').length;
  let char_count = textarea.length;

  document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = word_count;
  document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = char_count;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words()">
</textarea>
<p>Characters:
  <span id="char_count"></span>
  <br/> Words:
  <span id="word_count"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: wrong output for input `fd eff`, characters should be `5` while it gives `6`.

Comment: @rahul-kumar No, space is also a letter, ‍‍‍‍`fd eff` is `6` characters

Comment: here we need to count characters in words, otherwise the way you see it then there will be one word

Comment: If you assume space is also a character which is correct form the programmer's point of view not User's perspective.

Comment: No, it is not,
It is not mentioned in the question in this way,
The question states the number of letters in the text, not the word,
`I want to live count the characters and words in a user textarea‍`

Comment: @rahul-kumar
No, I do not accept,
Space is a char in any case,
Most people think of space as a char,
You can see it on different sites,
When the text limit is set, the space is also calculated

Comment: I'm talking about End User perspective, not developer, i know space or any other input key is char.

Comment: Let's take this example `fdfs   dss`, which has more than one space char in b/w, what should be word and char count?

Comment: For example ckeditor:
I suggest you try the latest version from the link below,
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/#classic

Comment: @rahul-kumar Do you accept ckeditor, which is a reputable editor, as a template for this?

Comment: @rahul-kumar in ckeditor `fdfs   dss` is `Words: 2` and `Characters: 8`

Comment: in your code it gives wrong word count: 4 for same input `fdfs   dss` having 3 spaces in b/w

Comment: @rahul-kumar My code is an example,
Considers each space as a word that is also said in the text,
Details and adding functionality to this topic are not relevant to this question

Answer (score 0):

- Use `split()` methods to split the word by spaces
- For each word count the no of characters using `Array.reduce()` function

```js
function count_chars_and_words(text) {
    const wordList = text.split(/ +/);
    const cc = wordList.reduce((count, word) => {
        return count + word.length;
    }, 0);
    document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = wordList.length;
    document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = cc;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words(value)"></textarea> 
                        <p>Characters: <span id="char_count"></span><br/>
                        Words: <span id="word_count"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 This will give word counts and character counts(space is not considered)
```

```js
 function count_chars_and_words() {
    const textarea = document.getElementById("text_count").value;
    const words = textarea.split(' ');
    let wc = words.length;
    let cc = textarea.length
        if(words[ wc-1] ==""){
        wc--;      
      cc--;
    }
    
    
     cc = wc==1?cc:cc- (wc-1);

    document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = wc;
    document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = cc;

  }
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words()"></textarea> 
                        <p>Characters: <span id="char_count"></span><br/>
                        Words: <span id="word_count"></span></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  function count_chars_and_words() {
    const textarea = document.getElementById("text_count").value;
    const wc = textarea.split(' ').length
    const cc = textarea.length


    document.getElementById("word_count").innerText = wc;
    document.getElementById("char_count").innerText = cc;

  }
```

```html
<textarea id="text_count" onkeyup="count_chars_and_words()"></textarea>
<p>Characters: <span id="char_count"></span><br/> Words: <span id="word_count"></span></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this one:

```
document.getElementById('text_count').onkeyup = function () {
 document.getElementById('char_count').innerHTML = this.value.length;
document.getElementById('word_count').innerHTML = this.value.split(' ').length;
};
```